# How do I keep a count of deduplicated messages from Logstash in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, deduplication

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037289/how-to-deduplicate-documents-while-indexing-into-elasticsearch-from-logstash) that document_id can easily be used in Logstash to replace a duplicate record in ElasticSearch. How would I add/increment a count value for e.g. repeating syslog messages? Instead of just replacing the record I want to increment the count so I know how many times it has repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are using to view the data, it might just be as simple as looking at the `_version` field of the documents.  ES will automatically update that value when something changes for the document.  Kibana doesn't show the _version field (https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/1234), but it's there.

Comment: Thanks, this may do the trick. I will need to do some testing to verify that the version number starts at 1 and increments by exactly 1 each time (and not under any other conditions), but this is definitely a good start. A related question might be whether there is a method for telling ES to increment a field rather than specifying a value. Ultimately I'm trying to decide if ES can function well as an event database (in which case records might be updated by other criteria besides a repeating message), but that by itself might be too broad of a question to post?

Comment: Elasticsearch can do [upserts](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html), but I don't think you can do that through Logstash

Comment: Aha, you beat me to it. :)  But yeah, will have to investigate the Logstash angle. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found what I need. An [upsert](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_upserts.html) will insert if a record doesn't exist, and update if it does. And enabling the [_source](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) field will allow incrementing of an existing field. That combination gives me the ability to start with a count of 1, and increment by 1 if the record already exists. Thanks @Alcanzar, your answer got my brain going in the right direction to find this.