# Logstash -> Elasticsearch : update document @timestamp if newer, discard if older

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Using the `elasticsearch output` in `logstash`, how can i update only the `@timestamp` for a log message if newer?

I don't want to reindex the whole document, nor have the same log message indexed twice.

Also, if the `@timestamp` is older, it must not update/replace the current version.

Currently, i'm doing this:

```
filter {
    if ("cloned" in [tags]) {
        fingerprint {
            add_tag => [ "lastlogin" ]
            key     => "lastlogin"
            method  => "SHA1"
        }
    }
}

output {
    if ("cloned" in [tags]) {
        elasticsearch {
            action              => "update"
            doc_as_upsert       => true
            document_id         => "%{fingerprint}"
            index               => "lastlogin-%{+YYYY.MM}"
            sniffing            => true
            template_overwrite  => true
        }
    }
}
```

---

It is similar to [How to deduplicate documents while indexing into elasticsearch from logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037289/how-to-deduplicate-documents-while-indexing-into-elasticsearch-from-logstash) but i do not want to always update the `message` field; only if the `@timestamp` field is more recent.

Answer (score 0):

You can't decide from Logstash level if a document needs to be updated or nothing should be done, this needs to be decided at Elasticsearch level. Which means that you need to experiment and test with `_update` API.

I suggest looking at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts. Meaning, if the document exists the script is executed (where you can check, if you want, the `@timestamp`), otherwise the content of `upsert` is considered as a new document.